# Calculating the gradient over a thrust::device_vector

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am currently transferring code from local C++ to CUDA, while working with `thrust::device_vector`s. Now there is a function to calculate the gradient where I also need to have access to non only the current element, but also the surrounding elements. In the original code I wrote the following:

```
void calc_grad(Complex *grad, const Complex *data, const int size)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
        grad[i] = 0.5 * (data[i + 1] - data[i - 1]);
    }
    grad[0] = data[1] - data[0];
    grad[size - 1] = data[size - 1] - data[size - 2];
}
```

Is it possible to create a `functor` for thrust out of that, such that I can call it in `thrust::transform()`? Up til now I only can access one element at the time, without getting the surrounding elements. Or is it not possible anyway, due to depending on elements before and afterwards, which are changed?

The formula for the code came from the `matlab` function `gradient`, shown here: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: You really should spend some time reading the thrust documentation: https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#gaa41d309b53fa03bf13fe35a184148400

Comment: This function is not doing what my function does. Are there other similar functions?

Comment: You can calculate any order accuracy scheme you like from successive differences calculated using `adjacent_differences`, including the second order central difference you have shown here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single [`Thrust::transform()`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#ga68a3ba7d332887f1332ca3bc04453792) can do most part of your work. All you need to do is to shift the data a little bit so that `grad[i]`, `data[i-1]` and `data[i+1]` are aligned.

```
thrust::transform(data.begin()+2,
                  data.end(),
                  data.begin(),
                  grad.begin()+1,
                  (_1 - _2) * 0.5);
```

Then you can deal with the boundary cases.

**Edit**

And you can also include the boundary cases in one transform. With the following form of transform, your functor `Grad` should be able to know the index of the data he is dealing with, by the first functor parameter. Based on the index, he can then choose 2 out of the 3 elements from the second functor parameter, which is a tuple, to do the correct calculation.

Everything here is not tested. I'm not sure if `data.begin()-1` works. You may also be careful on the `Complex` type.

```
thrust::transform(
  thrust::make_counting_iterator(int(0)),
  thrust::make_counting_iterator(int(0)) + size,
  thrust::make_zip_iterator(
      thrust::make_tuple(
          data.begin()-1,
          data.begin(),
          data.begin()+1)),
  grad.begin(),
  Grad(size)
);
```

The functor is something like this.

```
struct Grad {
  int size_;
  Grad(int s) :
      size_(s) {
  }
  template<typename T, typename Tuple>
  __host__ __device__
  inline T operator()(const int& idx, const Tuple& d) {
    if (idx == 0) {
      return d.get<2>() - d.get<1>();
    } else if (idx == size_ - 1) {
      return d.get<1>() - d.get<0>();
    } else {
      return 0.5 * (d.get<2>() - d.get<0>());
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Boundary cases: `grad[0] = data[1]-data[0]; grad[size-1] = grad[size-1]-grad[size-2];` or is there a faster way for that?

Comment: @arc_lupus I've edited the answer. It should have the same performance as the first one if it works.